# How to plot.bar base on other value than zero

Tags: python, matplotlib

Generally, the bar chart will show bottom on zero. which change the bottom, the bar move up or down.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 5
menMeans   = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)

ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, bottom=0,color='#d62728')

plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
plt.xticks(ind, ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
plt.legend('Men')
plt.savefig('bar.png')
plt.show()
```

while I want isn't moving up or down.  the following code show the bottom of zero.

I want to show the chart based on value such as 25. if the data,such as 20, then it shows 5 below the 25 in the chart. 
[image: the chart I want to get]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert `menMeans` to numpy and then subtract the bottom. Subtracting 25, the example array would be `[-5, 10,  5, 10,  2]`.

The x-axis can be moved to that height via `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', bottom))`. Similarly, the other spines can be made invisible (`ax.spines[...].set_color('none')`).

`plt.tick_params()` can remove the tick marks by setting their length to 0.

`ax.text(x, y, text)` can be used to set a text at a given position. Newlines can help to get an adequate padding independent of the y-axis.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
menMeans = np.array(menMeans)
ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence
bottom = 25
p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans-bottom, width, bottom=bottom, color='#d62728', label='Men')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
plt.xticks(ind, ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
plt.tick_params(axis='both', length=0)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', bottom))
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
for i, mean in zip(ind, menMeans):
    ax.text(i, mean, f'{mean}\n' if mean >= bottom else f'\n{mean}', ha='center', va='center')

plt.legend()
plt.savefig('bar.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]